# Why does IIS7 not accept a multiple level path in a virtual path - possible UI bug?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

In IIS7 you can't create a virtual path like so:

```
\SubFolder1\SubFolder2
```

as  a virtual path.  We had this set-up in IIS6 ok, but IIS7 doesn't accept \ symbols in the alias field.

The only way I can do this is to use the AppCmd.exe for IIS7 configuration and set the virtual path on the command line.  If it works on the command line, why not in the UI?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. While the '\' character is valid for the *path* of a virtual directory it is not valid in the *name* of a virtual directory which is what the *Alias* field is for.  The UI is for adding a virtaul directory in the selected location and is not designed to allow the creation of multiple levels of virtual directories at one time.

The command line confguration utility (appcmd.exe) allows almost absolute control over the actual configuration data and is not simply the same as the Management Console without a GUI.  If you have an advanced configuration need that is not met in the console then appcmd is the right way to do it.

Comment: So it seems from the UI, IIS7 does not allow virtual paths deeper than one level down?

Comment: As far as the UI goes, you are correct.  IIS will absolutely handle the configuration you are wanting but the Management Console can't do it in one step.  If you want to use the UI to do it you will need to create the first vdir and then create the second inside the first.